# Updates of user profile do not work once simple-schema is attached

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I've been trying to create a `userProfile` by attaching additional information to `Meteor.users` using the following packages:

- `aldeed:simple-schema`
- `aldeed:Collection2`
- `aldeed:AutoForm`

The update form generates and populates with the registered email address however I can't get the submit button to update anything to the database. My code is below.

Path: `collections/UserProfile.js`

```js
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
    optional: true
  }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
  emails: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
  },
  "emails.$": {
    type: Object
  },
  "emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  "emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
      return new Date()
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true
  },
  services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true,
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
});

Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
  }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Path: `client/UserProfile.js`

```js
Template.UserProfile.helpers({
  user: function(){
    return Meteor.user();
  },
  userSchema: function () {
    return Schema.User;
  }
});
```

Path: `client/UserProfile.html`

```js
{{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" doc=user id="user-profile-form" type="update"}}
```

Path: `server/publish.js`

```js
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have edited your post to shorten it and make it fitter for SO. Are you sure the whole schema is needed to reproduce your issue? See what is a [mcve].

Comment: See if it works without the field "emails.$"

Comment: Thanks for helping me format and shorten the code for SO @Kyll

Comment: I tried to removing the fields with "emails.$" it just crashed the application.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Or Submit button just doesn't doing anything?

Comment: Hi @dr.dimitru. Thanks for looking. This was awhile ago. I've change things so much that I'm not sure what the error was. This was one of my first posts to stack overflow should I close it somehow?

Comment: Hi @bp123 no, it's fine. But it will be better to find a solution you've used and answer on your own question. So others can enjoy your previous experience

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
{{> quickForm schema=userSchema doc=user id="user-profile-form" type="update"}}
```

and

```
Template.UserProfile.helpers({
 userSchema: function () {
   return Schema.User;
  }
});
```